# Database design to store user lang / locale : string in user table OR id - string in lang table and reference id in user table?

Tags: database-design

i m a noob and trying to figure out the best database design to :

store the user langage preference (en / fr / es / etc)

i have a user table, wich store the data like : email, sign in dates, etc

i am wondering if i should :

A. store the user language in this same table as a new column lang in a string format "en"

B. create a language table and insert there :

1 - en

2 - fr

3 - es

then make a reference to that table in my main user table, in a new column lang in Int format "1"

I guess it is a basic question, but that would help me understand best practice in database design, and get a good start in my learning.

Thanks in advance for all your advices and replies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a separate table, because you will probably want to store more data about the language then just the language code. For example, the full language name (for the language select box), ISO country codes, path to a flag image perhaps, or an index into a translation system for fetching the associated user interface strings.

Comment: both replies where interesting, i finally decided to go for a seperate table, to store the locale code (fr / en / es) and also the Labels for my drop down list in the 3 languages

Answer (score 0):

There are advantages and disadvantages to both. The following are my personal opinions.

If you have a separate table for the language field, you can use it as a lookup table to query for the possible allowed values if you need to. It allows you to add new values without having to modify the database schema validation rules.

However, having a table that just has one or two fields makes it more complicated for you to write queries because of additional joins depending on how many additional tables you have.

If you had more fields about the language e.g. language country, language setting etc, then it would make sense to use another table.

As you only seem to have one additional field, I feel it's best to to have the field in your existing table.

Comment: What do you mean by "database schema validation rules" ? Also if i go with the string in my main user table, how will i be able to retrieve the list of possible language and display them as a choice list ?